# my assembly language program jne not working

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I want to make an assembly language program on emu 8086 that has a dna as a string, takes every sequence (20 character long substring) and checks if it is a palindrome, if yes, it will print it in red, if not it will print it in white; it also removes the '-' working as separators for the sequences.
here i made a program but i have two issues : the first is the part that checks the palindrome, i put two characters in both al and bl then compare them, if they are not equal i stop and jump to print_white function, the problem is that even tho the al and bl are different, it still doesn't jump;
my last issue is : i don't know how to change colors, i tried multiple ways but they didn't work

here is my code :

```
org 100h 
jmp deb
m1:
dna dw 'GCAACCGCCAACGCGTATGA-GCGCGGATGCGCGCGGATGC-TTACGCGTAAAATGCGCATT-CTTCCGCACATCCCGCTACT-GCACGATGGTACCGGTCGCC-CCTGCCATGGTGTGATCCGC-CCGCTACTGCCGTCATCGCC-AAAATAGGCGCCACAGAAAC-GCAGAGGGGAAGGGGAGACG-CGCTCCTTCGGCTTCCTCGC-GTCCGGACCGTGCTGACCCC-AAAATAGGCGCCACAGAAAC-','$' ; this is dna
seq_size = 20 
string_size= $ - m1 
deb: 
lea di, dna
mov si, di
add si, seq_size 
dec si  
mov ah, 9
start: 
cmp [di], 45
jna stop 
cmp [di], 90
ja stop
   mov cx, seq_size  ;here is the palindrome part
   shr cx, 1        
   next_char:
       mov al, [di]
       mov bl, [si]
       cmp al, bl 
       jne print_white  ;here is the jne that is not working for me 
       inc di
       dec si
   loop next_char
   jmp print_red 

print_white :
        mov ax, 10
        sub ax, cx 
        mov cx, 19
        sub di, ax
            printing:
            mov dl, [di]
            mov ah, 2
            int 21h
            inc di 
        loop printing
        mov dl, [di]
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h
        inc di
        inc di
        jmp start

print_red: ;here is the part that i want to use to print the palindromes in red 
        mov ax, 10
        sub ax, cx 
        mov cx, 19
        sub di, ax
            printing2:
            mov dl, [di]
            mov ah, 2
            mov bl, 4 
            mov al, dl
            mov bh, 0
            int 21h
            inc di 
        loop printing2
        mov dl, [di]
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h
        inc di 
        inc di
        jmp start 

stop:
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

ret
```

Comment: You use `si` as an address and it even counts down, so the `cmp si, string_size` does not make sense. The `jne` should work.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE:** Written for NASM so there may be a few modifications needed for EMU8086

Try this on for size and notice how I changed the formatting of data area so it is a lot easier to identify that each entry is in fact the same length.

```
    org     0x100

            mov     si, Dna
            mov     cx, Entries

    Next:   lea     di, [si+TxtLen]
            push    di
            push    si

    ; Whenever DI and SI meet, we know it is a palindrome

       .L0: cmp     si, di
            jnz     .J0
            mov     bl, 7           ; Set color white
            jmp     Show

       .J0: dec     di
            lodsb
            cmp     al, [di]
            jz      .L0

    ; Chars did not match, not palindrome

            mov     bl, 4           ; Set color red

     Show:  pop     si              ; Points to beginning of string just evaluated

    ; At this point SI points to string to be printed and BL has the color WHITE or RED.
    ; Implement your printing routine and if need be, POP into a different register if you
    ; have too.        

            pop     si              ; Get pointer to beginning of next string
            loop    Next

            ret
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
            align 16        ; Aligning makes it easier to see in debug.

    Dna:    db  'GCAACCGCCAACGCGTATGA'

    TxtLen equ  $-Dna

            db  'GCGCGGATGCGCGCGGATGC'
            db  'TTACGCGTAAAATGCGCATT'
            db  'CTTCCGCACATCCCGCTACT'
            db  'GCACGATGGTACCGGTCGCC'
            db  'CCTGCCATGGTGTGATCCGC'
            db  'CCGCTACTGCCGTCATCGCC'
            db  'AAAATAGGCGCCACAGAAAC'
            db  'GCAGAGGGGAAGGGGAGACG'
            db  'CGCTCCTTCGGCTTCCTCGC'
            db  'GTCCGGACCGTGCTGACCCC'
            db  'AAAATAGGCGCCACAGAAAC'

    Entries      equ     ($-Dna) / TxtLen
```

Note too that I used DB not DW. Because the assembler (NASM) indentified it as a string, DW was ignored, but it is bad practice not to use the proper
data type.